# Failed to resolve Firebase library android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working on firebase for android and I have errors when I sync the project.

> Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0
>   Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0

[image]

build.grade(root):

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

build.gradle (app) :

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You need to add one more dependency. `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'` add this before `firebase-auth` dependency. Then clean and resync your gradle files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of google repository installed while using firebase. I faced the same issue in a certain project while integrating firebase, but it was resolved when I updated my SDK.

Comment: @FUN happy to help.

Answer (score 5):

Install latest version of **'Google Play services'** and **'Google Repository'**.

To install please follow below steps:

1. Open Android studio
2. Go to the Menu bar > Tools > Android > SDK Manager
3. Click on Tab > SDK Tools
4. Check and install **'Google Play Services'** and **'Google Repository'**
5. Click on Apply and wait for the download

Finally, **Sync** and **build** your project again.

Answer (score 0):

try with

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'`

**edit 1:**

I just checked that there is an update available for the Google Play Services and Android Support Repositories try updating that and then sync the Gradle files. Then you should be able to work with com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0 library as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem today. I updated Android Support Repository, Google Play Service and and Google Repository to the latest version through SDK Manager and that solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use this,

```
'compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'  '
```