# Firebase Auth - Google Play Store is missing

Tags: android, firebase

I am a newbie in Firebase, I have tried to make my first app with Firebase, it is just a register app, having two edit texts and a button 
I have added Firebase dependencies and google-service.json file to my test project

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build gradle (app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Build gradle (project) dependency

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my on click code is

```
public void register(){
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"fill all the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        progressDialog.setMessage("connecting..");
        progressDialog.show();
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            progressDialog.hide();

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

while executing the program showing the error 
here is the log;

```
03-14 13:31:31.585 1054-1772/system_process V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{f249820 u0 PopupWindow:5e4fee9} at 3 of 8 (after Window{d1abaee u0 dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample.MainActivity})
03-14 13:31:31.642 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 13:31:31.642 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe242b580, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 13:32:00.808 1054-1225/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
03-14 13:32:00.846 1054-1502/system_process V/WindowManager: not Base app: Adding window Window{4bd695 u0 dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample.MainActivity} at 3 of 8
03-14 13:32:00.852 2331-2619/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
03-14 13:32:00.852 2331-2619/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
03-14 13:32:00.911 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 13:32:00.912 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe242b720, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 13:32:01.335 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 13:32:01.335 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe247da20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 13:32:01.721 2331-2632/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample V/RenderScript: 0xeed9da00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
```

Comment: Can u please use the latest version of firebase-auth `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1` and try again

Comment: Still the same
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/data/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-10.0.1_c4eebdc719d0a4150992c3e03521d5c6758ad84c-classes.dex)

Comment: can u please update the question with the whole `build.gradle` file for both `app` and `project`.

Comment: @IbrahimAbousalem `10.2.0` is the latest version. @ Dcoder, try that version

Comment: failed to resolve 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'

Comment: @Dcoder check  this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323328/failed-to-resolve-firebase-library-android)

Comment: Why are you using compile? Use implementation instead

Answer (score 0):

try to use latest version which is

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
```

Comment: failed to resolve 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
failed to resolve  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'

Comment: update your sdk step by step
1) On Android studio, go to the menu bar and click on Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
2) Click on the SDK Tools tab
3) check the Google Play services box as well as the Google Repository box.
4) Click on apply, it will prompt you before applying the new updates.
5) Click Ok and wait for the download
Sync your project again and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to real device? Your device didn't have 'Google Play Store'.

You can  see this log.

```
03-14 13:32:00.852 2331-2619/dev.fbase.com.firebaseexample W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
```

if you want use firebase, you need android device or simultor with installed Google Play Services 10 or higher.